# the import android.media.image cannot be resolved

Tags: android

i'm getting the error 
"import android.media.image cannot be resolved" I searched the web for solution but couldn't find any thing

would you tell me what to do in order to fix this problem

thanks

Comment: try this import android.media.*;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import as

```
import android.media.*;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot import `android.media;` because it is a package, try to add this line

`import android.media.*;`

**or**

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer; // if you want to import MediaPlayer
import android.media.Ringtone;`
```